# Finding the limit of a pseudo geometric recurring sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

$$
a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2^{a_n}}
$$
Whilst practising to find the n-th term of a sequence, I haven't been able to successfully generalize this recurring sequence. I've called it pseudo geometric but honestly I got no idea what it's called, I would love to learn!

Things I've tried:

- In my calculator, this sequence converges to a value around $0.641185744$.
- We can assume the sequence to be geometric, so $k^{n+1}=\frac{1}{2^{k^n}}$, then $\log_2(k^{n+1})=\frac{1}{k^n}$ but I believe this is a dead end.

Answer (score 1):

The $n$-th term depends on the first term of the sequence. However this sequence do converge to the value you found. This value satisfies:

$$L = \frac1{2^L}, \text{ or } L\times 2^L = 1$$

A sequence of its decimal expansion is at https://oeis.org/A104748.

Its closed form involves the [Lambert W Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), which is non-elementary:

$$L\times 2^L = 1 \iff (L\ln 2)e^{L\ln 2} = \ln 2 \iff L \ln 2= W(\ln2)\iff L = \frac {W(\ln 2)}{\ln 2}$$

so the only way to obtain its value is by numerical approximation.

EDIT: The recurrence relation given is equivalent to:

$$a_{n+1} = \left(\frac12\right)^{a_n}$$

Given that $a_1=1$, we have the sequence:

$$\left\{1,\frac12, \left(\frac12\right)^\frac12, \left(\frac12\right)^{\left(\frac12\right)^\frac12},\left(\frac12\right)^{\left(\frac12\right)^{\left(\frac12\right)^\frac12}}, \dots\right\}$$

or, in [Tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) notation:

$$\left\{^0\left(\frac12\right),^1\left(\frac12\right),^2\left(\frac12\right),^3\left(\frac12\right)\dots\right\}$$

giving the "closed form" $a_n = ^{n-1}\left(\frac12\right)$.

Comment: I see I forgot to mention that I started with 1, silly me...

Comment: I understand why the number where the sequence converges satisfies that equation. This involvement with the Lambert W function is really interesting, however I don't have the capacity to understand it yet... Nonetheless this is answer showed me there is a lot to uncover by asking simple questions! Thanks